# Flash Programming - Anyone know how to work with an array of images?

Tags: flash, arrays, image

A friend has asked me to take a Flash 8.0 static image gallery website and make it dynamic.  Most articles I've found for dynamic image galleries involve loading the images on request into an existing movieclip.  I can't do this because there are some really neat transitions being used requiring both images to be available. I've figured out how to use the MovieClipLoader Class to load the images I need to an array of images but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to place them (and copy them) into specific layers.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to redo the gallery instead of trying to fix something old. Did you do the old project?

The basic logic would be like this:

You have to have:

- two containers
- a variable that saves which container is the active
- a list of the images to be loaded

The procedure should be like:

- load the first image into the first container and make it visible (the container)
- load the second image into the second container and make it NOT visible (the container)
- if the user wants to see the next image the transition goes off = the secont container gets visible and the the first gets hidden
- now load the third image into the first container, and kick the first image out // the logic to handle into which container you have to load you save in that one variable

Comment: You could expand it to N containers, one for each image.  Load all the images into their own containers, and hide all but the one you want visible.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would first work through this tutorial and see if you experience any ahHA moments.

http://flashexplained.com/actionscript/making-the-ultimate-dynamic-image-gallery-in-flash-8/

Answer (score 0):

This was the tutorial that I started with and realized I needed more.  This is what I was referring to when I referred to images being loaded on request.  What I need is for the images to be preloaded, probably in an array, then placed into different layers so they can make use of masks.

Comment: Just a friendly note: This isn't a forum, so if you want to respond to another persons answer you should add a comment. Hope you find the answer to your problem soon!